# Can't use Mixins coming from NPM Package of ZURB Foundation 6.4

Tags: webpack, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

Currently I try to setup ZURB Foundation 6.4 completely with Webpack 3. Basically the Sass part works fine. But as soon as I try to use a Mixin coming with ZURB Foundation 6.4 ([see my app.scss](https://github.com/digitaldomainwebsolutions/Webpack-Starter-Project/blob/feature/ZURB-Foundation/src/assets/scss/app.scss)) the console in phpStorm tells me the following:

`No mixin named breakpoint`

The whole Webpack 3 setup ([also my webpack.config.js](https://github.com/digitaldomainwebsolutions/Webpack-Starter-Project/blob/feature/ZURB-Foundation/webpack.config.js)) can be found at https://github.com/digitaldomainwebsolutions/Webpack-Starter-Project/tree/feature/ZURB-Foundation.

As far as I can see the (relative) paths in the NPM package ([foundation-sites](https://www.npmjs.com/package/foundation-sites)) are correct but I can't use the Mixins in any way.

Is there anybody able to help me out?

Comment: Did you try including this line in your app.scss?: `@import "foundation-sites/scss/util/breakpoint";`

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't work.
All the other needed SCSS files – including the `_mixins.scss` _ are referenced in `foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss`resp. in `util/util`.